# something weird happened to sshd. can only access through local network

Tags: networking, server, ssh

**VERY IMPORTANT EDIT**
Just because I can't understand the problem, I asked a friend to try to connect to it, and it works.
So I asked another friend to try, and it works.
**Apparently I'm the only one who can't connect to his own server remotely.**

Long story short: from one day to another I can't access to my server remotely through SSH.

```
ssh: connect to host "MY SERVER STATIC IP" port 22: Connection refused
```

I can access through the local network tho, without any problem.

I tried everything, I think.

```
netstat -tupan | grep ssh
```

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32536/sshd: /usr/sb
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      32536/sshd: /usr/sb
```

this is the output of the iptables

```
sudo iptables -S | grep 22
-A INPUT -s *some ip*/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DROP *** <- i have a list of like 20 ips blocked (i don't even know why)
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

as u can see I also tried by using ufw to add the port, and so on..

my /etc/ssh/sshd_conf is pretty standard. I tried to uncomment some lines

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf <- this line you will see later, i found it uncommented

Port 22
AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
ListenAddress ::
```

if I try to connect with -vvv I get this output

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "my server ip" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to "my server ip" [my server ip] port 22.
debug1: connect to address "my server ip" port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host "my server ip" port 22: Connection refused
```

what is this???
**debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files**

I forgot to mention that also my router has portforwarding enabled, and working with other services, like port 80 for apache.

I'm running ubuntu 19.10

Can you help me solving this mistery?
thanks

Comment: You seem to have conclusively demonstrated that your Ubuntu 19.10 server is not the problem. That's doubly good, because we no longer answer questions about 19.10 -- it reached End of Life ten months ago, and no longer receives security patches. Consider migrating to a supported release of Ubuntu. Were the server the issue, you would encounter the same problem when connecting locally. Time to reboot your router, and then check it's settings.

Comment: is the "my server ip" in your explanations an IP address on the internet.  If it is and you can ssh into the box on your local network then it sounds as though the issue is with the port forwarding configuration of your router.  Do you see any messages in /var/log/syslog or /var/log/ufw.log which show the packets to port 22 are being blocked?  If not then they are not getting past your router.

Comment: yes the "my server ip" is a public ipv4 address.

Comment: also I can't see any specific msg about the 22 port on the syslog or ufw.log 
but if i run a port scan I can see the ports are opened. Also, I repeat, port 80 is working fine.

Comment: Do you have fail2ban running? If so, did you get banned?

Comment: I didn't even know the existence of fail2ban, so no.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by reinstalling openssh, regenerating both pub and pvt keys, and updating all the keys in the `authorized_keys`

Couldn't find what the real problem was. Probably some kind of misconfiguration somewhere.